# Visual Studio debug assertion error, string subscript out of range. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to pass each character from a sample file to the string textArray for counting the number if characters in the file.
I can't figure out how to do it. I keep getting "subscript out of range" errors.

```
ifstream inData;

int main()
{
    float& totalchar = totalCharacters;
    float& nonletter = nonLetters;
    string textArray;

    inData.open("Text.txt");

    for (int i = 0; inData; i++)
    {
        textArray[i] = inData.get();
        if ((textArray[i] < 97 || textArray[i] > 122) && (textArray[i] < 65 
             || textArray[i] > 90))
        {
            nonletter++;
        }
    totalchar++;
    }
```

Comment: `textArray` is empty. `textArray[i]` is out of range for any `i`. You cannot add characters to a string this way.

Comment: You can use [`std::string::operator+=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) instead.

Comment: Strongly recommend using the letters rather than numbers. `if ((textArray[i] < 97 || textArray[i] > 122) && (textArray[i] < 65 || textArray[i] > 90))` is pretty abstract, but `if ((textArray[i] < 'a' || textArray[i] > 'z') && (textArray[i] < 'A' || textArray[i] > 'Z'))` shows exactly what you want to do. Better still is `std::isalpha`, which also has a fun overload for handling more complicated character sets.

Comment: `textArray += inData.get()` should work in your case. But why using `float` for integers

Comment: Floats are for another part of the code. += is not working. It seems n.m. is right, but if so then I don't know how to do this properly.